# Stack Empty Exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2012, stack, fifo

I am getting a stack empty exception. How is that possible if the stack is not empty (it has 16 items)?

I got a snap shot of the error:

[image: Stack Empty Exception]

Can someone please explain?

Comment: You've tagged this multithreading so I'm guessing many threads are accessing this code. I'm also guessing `SharedMemory` is not thread safe, and that you're not locking it. amiright?

Comment: What is `SharedMemory` in this context? and what is `full`?

Comment: Your question's title says "Stack empty", your first sentence says "Stack full". What is true here?

Comment: http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack.synchronized

Comment: @leppie that was discontinued for generics, IIRC. For the simple reason that it is useless. You can't safely use that API, because it only synchronizes **individual operations**. You can't check the count and then pop if > 0, because that is two **separate** operations, i.e. behavior is undefined

Comment: Shared Memory is of type Stack while full is an EventWaitHandler

Comment: full's logical meaning is that the stack has at least one item in it so it's full other wise it's not so it waits (full.WaitOne();)

Comment: @BeyondProgramming since `Stack` / `Stack<T>` are not listed as thread-safe, there is no defined behavior when accessing things like `.Count` / `.Pop()` / `.Push()` on different threads without synchronization, and it would be impossible to comment about the possible race scenarios without seeing the code that does the `Push()`. But ultimately the fix is going to be the same either way: you need to synchronize, or use a container that *is* thread-safe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You **must** synchronize access when using something like `Stack<T>`. The simplest approach is to use `lock`, which then also let's you use the `lock` for the synchronization itself; so pop would be:

```
int item;
lock (SharedMemory)
{
    while (SharedMemory.Count == 0)
    {
        Monitor.Wait(SharedMemory);
    }
    item = SharedMemory.Pop();
}
Console.WriteLine(item);
```

and push would be:

```
lock (SharedMemory)
{
    SharedMemory.Push(item);
    Monitor.PulseAll(SharedMemory);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't using the `ConcurrentStack<T>` as suggested by MBen be even more simple?

Comment: @codesparkle if it had a blocking `Pop` method, maybe; but it doesn't. It only has "get me something if something is there", aka `TryPop`

Comment: i found that a BlockingCollection<T> is better for the purpose of my program.(Producer/Consumer)

Answer (score 5):

> how is that possible the stack is full & has 16 items??!

In multithreading environment it is very much possible.

Are you using more than one threads in your program? If yes, `SharedMemory` should be `lock`ed before making any change to it.

Comment: ... and before querying it!

Answer (score 3):

If `SharedMemory` is a `Stack`, and since you are using Multithreading and if you are on .Net 4 . you should use : [ConcurrentStack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267331.aspx)

**Edit**

After my first edit and a great comment from **Quartermeister** this a simpler working solution:

```
    int item;
    var SharedMemory = new BlockingCollection<int>(new ConcurrentStack<int>());
    // later in the Consume part
    item = SharedMemory.Take(); // this will block until there is an item in the list
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Comment: `ConcurrentStack<>` only has `TryPop`, so if (as per the question) you want a blocking-pop setup, it doesn't really get any simpler by using that API.

Comment: @MarcGravell didn't see the blocking-pop :)

Comment: @MarcGravell still, isn't better to simplify the code using ConcurrentStack?

Comment: not if it doesn't simplify it any; you'll still have most of the same code, and you'll need to think very carefully about thread-races between the gate being set and the "pop". By all means, though, feel free to edit in a robust implementation that behaves in the desired way. I just sincerely doubt it will be any simpler.

Comment: i'll try what you suggest & if it works i'll inform you with the results.

Comment: @MarcGravell You were right. Unfortunatly you get an exception that it is not locked (which is true). Would be nice if those collection offer some blocking mechanism like BlockingCollection<T>

Comment: You can wrap the ConcurrentStack in a BlockingCollection.  The default constructor of BlockingCollection uses a ConcurrentQueue, but there is another constructor that takes an IProducerConsumerCollection, and you can pass a ConcurrentStack to that constructor to get a blocking LIFO collection.

Comment: @Quartermeister excellent, I learned something new. I updated the answer