# How to Fix Cross-thread error When using Task Parallel library?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

```
 List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
 tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => functionA()));
 tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => functionB()));
 tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => functionC()));



 function A(){
  List<string>lstResult =Get list ();
  control.DataSource =lstResult ;
  control.Databind();
  }



   function B(){
     List<string>lstResult =Get list ();
     control.DataSource =lstResult ;
     control.Databind();
   }



   function C(){
    List<string>lstResult =Get list ();
    control.DataSource =lstResult ;
    control.Databind();
    }
```

Here, I am getting Stack Empty exception because of concurrency Issue. How to solve this one. I came across this one [Stack Empty Excetpion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121799/stack-empty-exception)  but nowhere it is mentioned how to overcome this issue.

Comment: You cannot update a Control on the Thread Pool thread, this would not work, Update controls on main thread

Comment: what's your use case, how come same control is getting updated in three different Tasks ?

Comment: Those are different drop downs. Not updating the same drop-down every time.

Comment: `async/await` does away with this problem. Instead of using `Task.Run` on the entire method, use it *only* on the actual long-running job, eg `var results = await Task.Run(()=>Getlist ();`. You should clean up the UI update code as well. Do you *really* want to keep only the last UI changes?

Comment: @HemanthKrishna btw this has nothing to do with a "Stack empty" exception. This code won't raise that exception at all. There are *many* duplicates for the actual exception that expalin that  you just *can't* update the UI from another thread, and how to fix this

Comment: Nope. It is raising "Stack Empty" exception.

Comment: @HemanthKrishna there's no such exception. Exceptions are classes. Class names can't have spaces in their names. Post the *actual* exception, including its name, message and call stack. You can get all of them easily with `Exception.ToString()`. Your current code is guaranteed to throw an InvalidOperationException whose message complains about cross-thread modifications if it's used in a desktop application. Perhaps the exception is thrown by code you haven't posted, before the UI is updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't modify the UI from another thread, in any operating system. This code can be simplified a lot if `async/await` is used and `Task.Run` moves *inside* the functions, eg :

```
async Task functionA(){
    var results= await Task.Run(()=>Getlist1();
    control1.DataSource =results ;
    control1.Databind();
}

async Task functionB(){
    var results= await Task.Run(()=>Getlist2();
    control2.DataSource =results ;
    control2.Databind();
}

async Task functionC(){
    var results= await Task.Run(()=>Getlist3();
    control3.DataSource =results ;
    control3.Databind();
}


var tasks = await Task.WhenAll( functionA(),
                                functionB(),
                                functionC());
```

`await` awaits for an already asynchronous operation to complete without blocking. When that operation completes, it returns execution to the original thread, in this case the UI thread

Answer (score 0):

Your `control` object can be accessed by multiple threads at the same time. To solve this issue, you have to use `MethodInvoker` like this:

```
function A(){
    List<string> lstResult =Getlist();
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
    {
        control.DataSource =lstResult ;
        control.Databind();
    }));
}
```

Comment: `Getlist()` shall be moved out of the `MethodInvoker`, that can be executed on separate thread pool thread

Comment: The control I am using is Telerik Radcombox Control and It doesn't have Invoke function. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Yes, you should define delegates: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls .

Comment: @koviroli that's *not* how Invoke is meant to work and can easily lead to deadlocks. It should be called on the *control* that's meant to be updated. It's also not needed when `async/await` is available

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks, I will know it next time.